# Flutter build failed with exception :path_provider_android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sqflite

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider_android'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.19\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --d`enter code here`ebug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.